# Why isn't str.trim() removing all the whitespace with certain words?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to take a text file that has assembly-like code inside it and parsing it into an array in java. The text file looks like this:

```
        begin
        LDA #10     ;load $0A into accumulator
        LDX $15      ;load $15m into X
_loop   TAX         ;transfer A to X 
        SEC         ;set carry flag
        end
```

At the moment the code I have reads the text file line by line and stores each line as a separate string in an array. This works fine, and the code keeps the whitespace in the strings as expected. Next I pass each line from the array to the code below, this then divides each line up using `str.split(" ")` and then trims each new string before placing it into another array and returning the array.

So just to be clear the process goes like this:

1. `LDA #10     ;load $0A into accumulator` one large line
2. `dividedLine[] = ["LDA", "#10", ";load", "etc.."]` line is divided up into its elements

The only problem is that with some of the words the whitespace is removed entirely by `str.trim()` but with some other words the whitespace remains. I think it might be something to do with the tabs I'm using but I'm not sure.

Here's the output I'm getting:

`beginLDA#10;load$0AintoaccumulatorLDX$15;load$15mintoX_loop    TAX     ;transferAtoXSEC        ;setcarryflagend`

As you can see there is a large amount of whitespace between 'loop' and 'TAX' and between 'SEC' and ';set' which shouldn't be there.

Here's the raw text file I'm using, since I altered it a bit to make it easier to read on stack: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c802ca31d5402c702ada237bea47f223

Here's my code:

```
public String[] divideLine(String line) 
    {
        String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
        for(String str : lineArray)
        {
            str = str.trim();
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        return lineArray;
    }
```

If it is the tabs causing the problem, is there a way I can convert all tabs to spaces before processing each line?

Comment: try split("\\s+"), this will split around any whitespace where as " " only splits it around a single white space.

Comment: I wouldn't use `split()` at all for this. Just write a few lines of code to parse the format. There are only three columns, after all. You don't want to de-space the comments, for example.

Comment: Try `line.trim().split("\\s+")`. That way, you won't need to `trim()` the words in the returned array, since they've already been trimmed. The `trim()` before `split()` is to ensure you don't get an empty words as the first value.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: An easier solution might be using [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: View the file in a hex viewer, perhaps the spaces you see are tabs instead

Answer (score 0):

If you split on a single whitespace character then the pieces will have tabs some places which accounts for the whitespace you see.

For example, the fifth line of your raw file is

`SEC     ;set carry flag`, or with the tab character as \t,

`\tSEC\t\t;set carry flag`

`"  SEC     ;set carry flag".split(" ")` returns the array

`[  SEC     ;set, carry, flag]`,

or with the tab character as \t, you have

`[\tSEC\t\t;set, carry, flag]`

As others have mentioned, you can change your code to split on a different regex like `"\\s+"`.

Answer (score 0):

May be apache's library `commons-lang3` will be helpful. There's class `StringUtils` in that library.

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#normalizeSpace-java.lang.String-

`normalizeSpace` removes starting and ending spaces and replaces each sequence of space-like symbols to 1 space. I think it is what you want.